# tm date outputs wrong date in c++?

Tags: c++, date, visual-c++, time, calendar

I have a c++ program with:

```
std::tm date{};
date.tm_year = 2023 - 1900;
date.tm_wday = 0;
date.tm_yday = (50 - 1) * 7;
std::mktime(&date);
std::cout << std::put_time(&date, "%A, %B %d, %Y") << std::endl;
```

I expect it to output today's date which is Sunday, December 10, 2023, but it outputs Saturday, December 31, 2022.
I cannot find out what is causing this problem.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]? The code you posed can't be compiled. If you talk about the output, be kind to post a code that raises the mentioned output but not the output `error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'`... Don't force SO users to fix compiler errors, they may eliminate the issue while getting the code compiled.

Comment: What's the purpose / meaning of the magic number 50?  There are 52 weeks in a year, so that's not a possibility.

Comment: A quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime): _"`time->tm_wday` and `time->tm_yday` are **ignored.**"_ (emphasis mine).

Comment: Just fyi, a C++20 solution: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZMDcliQwc8YsgCU6

Answer (score 0):

[`std::mktime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) does not use the `tm::tm_wday` or `tm::tm_yday` fields as input, only as output.  You need to pass in the `tm::tm_mon` and `tm::tm_mday` fields instead, as well as the `tm::tm_isdst` field since you are converting from local time.

Also, note that [`std::put_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) expects a `std::tm` from [`std::localtime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) or [`std::gmttime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/gmtime), not from `std::mktime()`.

This is the example from the `std::mktime()` documentation on cppreference.com:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
 
int main()
{
    setenv("TZ", "/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles", 1); // POSIX-specific
 
    std::tm tm{}; // Zero initialise
    tm.tm_year = 2020 - 1900; // 2020
    tm.tm_mon = 2 - 1; // February
    tm.tm_mday = 15; // 15th
    tm.tm_hour = 10;
    tm.tm_min = 15;
    tm.tm_isdst = 0; // Not daylight saving
    std::time_t t = std::mktime(&tm); 
    std::tm local = *std::localtime(&t);
 
    std::cout << "local: " << std::put_time(&local, "%c %Z") << '\n';
}
```

If you just want today's date, use [`std::time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) instead of `std::mktime()`:

```
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::tm date = *std::localtime(&t);
std::cout << std::put_time(&date, "%A, %B %d, %Y") << std::endl;
```